# For the vector field: $F = (x^2 + y^2 +3x)i - (2xy + y)j$, find the scalar field $f(r)$ such that $\nabla f = (\nabla \cdot F)\cdot F$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

For the vector field: $F = (x^2 + y^2 +3x)i - (2xy + y)j$, find the scalar field $f(r)$ such that $\nabla f = (\nabla \cdot F)\cdot F$.

Now I have found that F is irrotational however I am unsure how to progress since I cannot make sense of the question.

Computing the divergence of F yields a scalar field so how can we then find the dot product of that with F?

Unless they simply mean that F is 'multiplied' by a scalar?

Just want to make sure before I continue.

Thanks a million!!

My Attempt:

$\nabla \cdot F = \frac{\partial (x^2 + y^2 +3x)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial (2xy +y)}{\partial y} = (2x - 2y -1)$

Which means:

$(\nabla \cdot F) \cdot F = (2x - 2y -1) [(x^2 + y^2 +3x)i - (2xy + y)j]$

But seems odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is solve the following equations,

$$ (f_x,f_y) = \bigg(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) \bullet (x^2+y^2+3x,-2xy-y)\bigg) \cdot (x^2+y^2+3x,-2xy-y)$$

Comment: Oh ok well I was on the right track then thanks!!

Comment: Wait I am unsure what you mean by tack on the $i,j$ components. When you compute the divergence in the brackets you don't get any $i,j$ components right?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. What can't be the case is that the second $\cdot$ is dot product, it must be scalar multiplication.

Comment: Let me know if this works, also re-read the question and make sure the notation is correct.